# lodash while filtering ignore few values

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

I am using lodash's filter function to filter an array. The array has some objects with `disabled` set to true that need to be shown all the time. I also want all objects in the array that has a value of `v` that is present in `obj`.

```
var obj = ["98100","99100"];

var mainObj = [
  {"v":"99999","d":"United States (National)","disabled":false},
  {"v":"98999","d":"Census Regions and Divisions","disabled":true},
  {"v":"98100","d":"Northeast Region","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99100","d":"New England Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99120","d":"Middle Atlantic Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"98200","d":"South Region","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99140","d":"South Atlantic Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99130","d":"East South Central Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99170","d":"West South Central Census Division","disabled":false}
];
```

How do I get those values?

My code:

```
var arr = _.filter(mainObj, function(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (item.v === obj[i]) {
      return true;                                      
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To return every object in the array that has a value of `v` that is present in the `obj`, and return every object that is disabled, you could use this predicate:

```
var result = _.filter(mainObj, function(el) {
  return el.disabled === true || obj.indexOf(el.v) !== -1;
});
```

```js
var obj = ["98100","99100"];
var mainObj = [
  {"v":"99999","d":"United States (National)","disabled":false},
  {"v":"98999","d":"Census Regions and Divisions","disabled":true},
  {"v":"98100","d":"Northeast Region","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99100","d":"New England Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99120","d":"Middle Atlantic Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"98200","d":"South Region","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99140","d":"South Atlantic Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99130","d":"East South Central Census Division","disabled":false},
  {"v":"99170","d":"West South Central Census Division","disabled":false}
];

var result = _.filter(mainObj, function(el) {
  return el.disabled === true || obj.indexOf(el.v) !== -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank!. But it doesn't maintiain the order. In the given example ["98100","99100"] are under 98999. So it should come as 98999 under it ["98100","99100"] . Where as 98999 comes at the end. I see it disabled though

Comment: @user1015388 I'm not sure I understand :) `98999` is first in `mainObj` and first in the resulting array.

Comment: ,Yes, but for some reason all the disabled=true are returned at the end.

Comment: Got it. My sorting is messing up the order. I had a similar logic earlier too, it was returning the same, since I didn't notice sorting messing up, i posted it